# Laravel dropColumn() migration with Docker

Tags: laravel, docker, mariadb

I have just installed a new project with Docker and it does have several dropColumn() methods in migrations. For some reason, it couldn't drop columns, though it can create and change columns, tables. Message I'd get:

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: alter table `apartments` drop `square`)
```

Database Docker-compose part:

```
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - ${DB_PATH_HOST}:/var/lib/mysql
```

Migration:

```
        Schema::table('apartments', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->dropColumn('square');
            $table->dropColumn('price');
            $table->dropColumn('description');
        });
```

.env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mariadb
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=project
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

I already have tried to install doctrine/dbal but nothing have changed. What could be an issue?

Comment: of course, it can run migrations and seed the database. The only problem with dropping the column. But when I trying to do it though Adminer everything works.

Comment: The error message indicates that MariaDB isn't fully running before the SQL was executed. Downgrading a version may not save you as you're still subject to race conditions. Look at doing a healthcheck over tcp to ensure the service is up before other interactions.

Answer (score 0):

I've downgraded MariaDB version to `image: mariadb:10.3` and it worked.

UPD:

On other hand, switching from `$table->foreignId('blog_reply_id')->nullable()->constrained('blog_replies')->onDelete('cascade');`

to
`$table->bigInteger('blog_reply_id')->nullable()->constrained('blog_replies')->onDelete('cascade');`

Would make all things work perfectly even on latest MariaDB version.